# Sound Settings won't let me switch Bluetooth headset to A2DP

Tags: sound, bluetooth, a2dp

This issue has been cropping up for a while.  Sometimes my BT headset works fine, and other times I can't switch the output to A2DP.  When I go into sound settings and try and switch from HSP/HFP to A2DP it reverts the output back to the speaker.  There seems to be no way to choose A2DP.

I'm attaching a gif below to show this behavior.

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frt9L.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

i have this problem as well , i found a pattern that works.

connect headset , try to change to A2DP , disconnect headset , reconnect headset , change to A2DP , it will then work

Comment: Yeah, I found that pavucontrol as well seems to work.  Not sure what order of commands forces it eventually to connect through A2DP.  It'd be nice if this "just worked"™.

Comment: it used to in 15.10 with the same hardware , hopefully this regression will be short lived

Comment: this behaviour has changed in 18.10 where is seems to be able to remember settings properly